# extracting values based on regex

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column which has urls, So below are the values of the column

```
https://www.example.com/jasja
https://www.example.com/jasdqw?new=exact
```

So what I want to extract is before the question mark and after the last slash

So here my output in the column should be

```
jasja
jasdqw
```

How can I get this using Regex
Tried `=REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C16, SPLIT())`, but don't know how to use this

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `REGEXEXTRACT` with a capture group:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C2, "/([^/]+?)(?:\?|$)")
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WjOq10/1).

Comment: Thanks for the response but getting like this for second url jasdqw?new=exact,  the remaining part is not getting removed

Comment: yep its working, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
=RegexExtract(A1,".*/(.*?)\?")
```

[image]